# How many times can I have jQuery's document ready function declared on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How many times is it permitted to have the jQuery document ready function declared on a page, i.e.:

```
$(function () { ... });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

Is there any difference between the two?

If it's permitted more than one, do they fire in order of declaration?

Comment: 42... or: exactly as often as you can have `$(element).click(function() {...})` for the same element ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**One:** There is no difference between the two.

Quote:

```
All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
```

**Two**: You can have as many of them as you wish, and they will be executed in the order that the `$()` or `$(document).ready()` functions are executed. (i.e. each handler is added to the queue)

Comment: Observation: When the OP asks "how many", it's best not to start your answer with "One".

Answer (score 13):

As many as you need.

The document ready function adds to what is essentially an event queue - the functions in these declarations will all be executed, either at the document.ready event, or immediately if that event has already fired, in order of declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As many times as you like. They fire in order of declaration.

`$(document).ready()` will fire when the document is ready (when it's all loaded by the browser). The other one will fire as soon as that part of the script executes.

Comment: *"They fire in order of declaration."* No, they fire in order of *execution* (the order in which you executed the `ready` or hyper-overloaded `$` function). You can *declare* your function you pass into those anywhere. (A small point, but precision can really matter with these things.) http://jsbin.com/ulevi3

Comment: `$(function() { ... })` is actually equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Comment: The *other one*? Which other one` The first one? It is exactly the same, just shorthand syntax.