# How many times $(function () {}); could be used in jQuery at same js file?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if there is any sense on using the code bellow more than one time on same js type file and also what it does if used inside another document ready.

```
$(function () {
    //some code
});
$(function () {
    //some other code
    $(function () {
        //does this here make any sense?
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471349/how-many-times-can-i-have-jquerys-document-ready-function-declared-on-a-page

Comment: Are you missing a `)` or something?  I think your code pasted wrong.

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` after each `}`

Comment: `if ( 1 == 1 ) { if (1 == 1) { if (1 == 1) { alert("1 == 1!") } } }`

Comment: What do you want to achieve by nesting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How many times $(function () {}); could be used in jQuery at same js file?*

Technically Any number of time.

But one inside another doesn't make any sense

*like this one doesn't make any sense*

```
$(function () {
    //some other code
    $(function () {
        //does this here make any sense?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(function() { })` is a direct equivalent for `$(document).ready(function() { });`. As such, whilst the first makes sense, the second definitely does not. If you know that `DOMContentLoaded` has fired...Why do you tell jQuery to test again?

Comment: [I see you're trying to use jQuery within jQuery. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)